# Sqlite Database gets deleted from Documents Folder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

We have an iOS application for the iphone that is having strange behavior. I store some data of the app in an SQLite Database file in the documents folder. Every once in a while i realize that when the application crashes the file on the disk gets deleted. And i can´t figure out why the app would do this...Any Ideas?!

Comment: Could you specify the filepath of the database?

Comment: /var/mobile/Applications/2C06F31D-9CA7-4597-8F5B-837F7ED05BFA/Documents/datenbankSpeed

Comment: Do you hardcode it? Or do you find that filepath programmatically?

Comment: No, and i get the path like this: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datenbankSpeed"];

Comment: This might be useful to double-check: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: And have you only tested on the simulator? Have you tested the application on a device? You might have a setting which wipes the sandbox folders after a build or clean.

Comment: Nah, i only tested it on a device! not in the simulator!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25606/discussion-between-nathan-white-and-chrizstone)

Comment: Make sure you've studied the [Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/).

Comment: Yes, i did...but theres nothing to help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution...If i save my database in the Cache Directory instead of the Documents directory, it works...:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're saving any documents for the application to the application's private folder in the documents. I use this:

`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainask, YES) lastObject];`